# Is there a way to group models using sequelize?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm using `sequelize` with `postgres` and in the database definition there are two database schemas, `counter` and `schedule`, each schema have a table with the name `events` (used for different purposes) and when defining the sequelize models I currently have to name one of the two models that references to the `events` table in a different way because I can't name the two as `event`.

Is it possible to define a model in a type of namespace or group? Something like this:

```
// models/counter/event.js
const event = sequelize.define(
    'counter.event',
    {
        title: {
            type: dataTypes.STRING(64),
            allowNull: false
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
        tableName: 'events',
        schema: 'counter'
    }
);

// models/schedule/event.js
const event = sequelize.define(
    'schedule.event',
    {
        title: {
            type: dataTypes.STRING(64),
            allowNull: false
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
        tableName: 'events',
        schema: 'schedule'
    }
);

// index.js
sequelize.import(Path.join(__dirname, './models/counter/event'));
sequelize.import(Path.join(__dirname, './models/schedule/event'));

const counterEvents = sequelize.models.counter.event.findAll();
const scheduleEvents = sequelize.models.schedule.event.findAll();
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why not just name them `CounterEvent` and `ModelEvent`, is there a problem with this? No, I doubt that sequelize supports nesting on its `.models`.

Comment: Yeah, I know I can do that, I was just wondering if there were a possibility...